# Unsetting array adds key to objects in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, unset

From a json feed, I need four objects from
`$json['content']['locations']['location']['cams']['cam']['snow']['wi']`

It contains 5 objects. I need Object 0, Object 1, Object 3 and Object 4. This is what I did: 
`unset($json['content']['locations']['location']['cams']['cam']['snow']['wi'][2]);`

Before each object appeared a key (index) after doing this. I don't need and don't want these keys.
Array_values() doesn't solve the problem.

`$reindex = array_values($json); 
    $json = $reindex;`

Live:

http://www.api.bart-ros.nl/raurisertal/info2test (4 objects, keys present)

http://www.api.bart-ros.nl/raurisertal/info2 (5 objects, keys absent)

How to get it like the second link?

**SOLUTION**

`unset($json['content']['locations']['location']['cams']['cam']['snow']['wi'][2]); 
    $reindex = array_values($json['content']['locations']['location']['cams']['cam']['snow']['wi']); 
    $json['content']['locations']['location']['cams']['cam']['snow']['wi'] = $reindex;`

Comment: How are using array_values()? It should do the job.

Comment: array_values() does nothing, i saw a second ago.

Comment: How do you encode to JSON? Looks like json_encode with JSON_FORCE_OBJECT option.

Comment: You want the values of $json['content']['locations']['location']['cams']['cam']['snow']['wi'], not the values of just $json.

Comment: The json originally was XML: $simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($fileContents); $json = json_encode($simpleXml);

Comment: @kainaw You solved the problem. Thanks! :D See updated Question for my solution.

Comment: Don't post the solution into the question! It's confusing. Write it as an answer and explain how/why it works, what functions do you use and why etc. This way both the question and the answer are readable and useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

`$reindex = array_values($json); 
 $json = $reindex;`

to

`$reindex = array_values($json['content']['locations']['location']['cams']['cam']['snow']['wi']); 
$json['content']['locations']['location']['cams']['cam']['snow']['wi'] = $reindex;`

did the trick.